# phpのpreg_matchが上手く効かない

Tags: php, 正規表現

PHPにてDBをUPDATEするためのソースを記述していて、バリデーションのためにIFでチェック
しようとしています。
しかしながら、「英数字記号以外ならばtrueを返してエラーを表示」すると記述している
つもりですが、英字のみで書いてもエラーになってしまいます。
エラー内容は「ユーザー・パスワードは半角英数字記号で入力します。」です。
試しに英数字記号（英字は大文字・小文字含む）を全て含めてみても結果は同じでした。
原因と思われる部分をお聞かせいただきたく存じます。
コードを添付します。

```
<?php 
var_dump($_REQUEST['password']);
try{
    require_once('db_connect.php');
    $sql=$pdo->prepare('update user_table set last_name=?, first_name=?, last_name_kana=?, first_name_kana=?, user=?, password=? where id=? ');
        if(empty($_REQUEST['sei']) || empty($_REQUEST['mei']) || empty($_REQUEST['sei_kana']) || empty($_REQUEST['mei_kana']) || empty($_REQUEST['user']) || empty($_REQUEST['password']))
            {
                echo '未入力の項目があります。';
            }
            else if(!preg_match('/\A[ア-ヿ]+\z/u', $_REQUEST['sei_kana']) || !preg_match('/\A[ア-ヿ]+\z/u', $_REQUEST['mei_kana']))
                {
                     echo 'カナ名は全角カナで入力してください。';
                }
                else if(!preg_match('<^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%()*+-./:;=?@[]^_`{|}]{1,}$>', $_REQUEST['user']) || !preg_match('<^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%()*+-./:;=?@[]^_`{|}]{1,}$>', $_REQUEST['password']))
                    {
                        echo 'ユーザー・パスワードは半角英数字記号で入力します。';
                    }
                    else if($_REQUEST['password'] !== $_REQUEST['password2'])
                        {
                            echo '2つのパスワードが一致してません。';
                        }
                        else if($sql->execute([htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['sei'],$_REQUEST['mei'],$_REQUEST['sei_kana'],$_REQUEST['mei_kana'],$_REQUEST['user'],$_REQUEST['password'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')]))
                            {
                                echo '更新に成功しました。';
                            }
                                else {
                                        echo '更新に失敗しました。';
                                    }}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "次がエラーの内容です。;" .$e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.preg-match.php)のパターンが`<`で始まり`>`で終わっていることが原因のように思います。
`<>`は`?P<name>`のような構文で[名前付きサブパターン](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)として利用することが多いです。
`/`で前後を囲むコードの誤字でしょうか？コードに意図がある場合は質問に追記してください。

**サンプルコード**

```
<?php
print(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%()*+-\.\/:;=?@\[\]^_`{|}]{1,}$/', 'azAZ09!#$%()=|-^`{+*}?_@[;:],./')); //"&<>'~\
print(preg_match('/^[!-~]+$/', 'azAZ09!"#$%&\'()=~|-^`{+*}<>?_@[;:],.\\/'));
?>
```

サンプルコードの上段がパスワードチェック用の正規表現を書き直したものです。
下段が英数字記号を1文字以上含む正規表現の例です。
下段の例は上段で対象外となる記号の`"&<>'~\`を許容するのでご注意ください。

**参考資料**

- [phpで文字列に「英数字記号」を含むかどうかチェックしたい](https://teratail.com/questions/102616)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。タイプミスでした。修正して解決しました。